# Process output not showing in real time & no complete

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

When I click button the process output not showing in real time and after process completed its still loading and button not clickable

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    this.button2.Enabled = false;

    processCaller = new ProcessCaller(this);
    processCaller.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
    processCaller.Arguments = (@"/k chcp 1252 & %cd%\env\bin\ruby.exe %cd%\files\wpscan.rb --no-color --update");
    processCaller.StdErrReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
    processCaller.StdOutReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
    processCaller.Completed += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCanceled);
    processCaller.Cancelled += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCanceled);
    //processCaller.Failed += no event handler for this one, yet;

    this.textBox3.Text = "Started function.  Please stand by.." + Environment.NewLine;

    // the following function starts a process and returns immediately,
    // thus allowing the form to stay responsive.
    processCaller.Start();  
}
```

[The full code is here](http://pastebin.com/8YmN4vdP)

Comment: Where do you set the button to enabled again?

Comment: What is this `ProcessCaller` class? What do your handlers do? Have you tried running the same code in the console to see if there actually is any output?

Comment: the full code here : http://pastebin.com/8YmN4vdP

Comment: For anyone interested, the pastebin code seems to be adapted (more like copy-pasted) from [here](https://github.com/actualmanx/BatchFileRealtime). I don't feel like debugging the whole thing today. My guess: the process that you're starting hangs and never outputs anything.